# How to perform logging out in iPhone application?

Tags: php, iphone, objective-c, authentication, logout

I know nothing about PHP, but in my application I need to implement user login and logout. I've found this [nice tutorial](http://kiksy.tumblr.com/post/525713227/iphone-login-app-using-php-mysql-tutorial) and have successfully implemented logging in, but how do I log out? I just can't find any information about it in google, particularly about iPhone side. PHP tutorials mostly explain a lot of theory about sessions and stuff like that which is not applicable for my specific event.  I would love to spend my time for  learning that theory, but I have to learn PHP basics first and this is not what I currently need.

All I need is to understand the correct way of implementing logout.

1. I would be glad very much if someone explained me shortly in plain language the mechanism of standard interaction between iPhone app and php script when logging in and out.
2. This is more important. Would you please provide me with few lines of php and objective- с code displaying how to implement logging out?

Comment: What you exactly need? Logout by timeout or logout by users activity? If by activity - don't think it's a problem, just call URL, which would be success, if user logged out, or error, if not. On PHP side - just unset $_SESSION by session_close(), if you're using sessions, if cookie - then just kill cookie by setcookie(). If by time out - set up a cron job, just say what you need, and I'll explain the details if you need ones.

Comment: That first of all depends on how you're implementing the *login*. Session based I suppose? Then you only have to throw away the cookie on the client and destroy the session on the server. That's one function call for each.

Comment: quick tip, use `mysql_real_escape_string` in php to stop sql injection(bad!) eg. `$u = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET[‘username’]);` and
`$pw = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET[‘password’]);`

Comment: sorry, not session_close() - session_destroy()

Comment: devdRew   I need to log out by users activity. Could you please explain "just call URL, which would be success, if user logged out, or error, if not" a litle bit in detail, i can't grasp it

Comment: deceze  Hm... can you please give me a hint about how to throw away cookie on iphone side? i just can't find it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In our app we use this schema:

Login I'll jumpover (that you've done)

When the user logout our application call an URL, which is considered for logout. For example: http://ourcoresyste.com/logout.php

Sorry for inconvinience, but I'm not iOS developer, so I don't know exactly how application makes call, but I think you should know it, if login is done.

In the script logout.php:

```
<?php
    if (!isset($_SESSION))
    {
        exit(json_encode(array('code' => 0, 'message' => 'Logout successful')));
    }
    esle
    {
        $user = $_SESSION['user_id']; // suppose you have stored into $_SESSION['user_id'] logged in user;
        // Do some stuff while logout, maybe some DB interactions.
        if ($shit_happens)
        {
            exit(json_encode(array('code' => 1, 'message' => 'Shit happens')));
        }
        unset($_SESSION['user_id']); // or session_destroy(), if you want completly remove all information about user.
        exit(json_encode(array('code' => 0, 'message' => 'Logout successful')));
    }
```

Than in your app you parse JSON response which will be like this:

```
{"code":0,"message":"Your detailed message"}
```

And decide by code retrieved from JSON response, were user logged out or not. If he was, next time you call any PHP script, which relies on $_SESSION['user_id'], will fail, probably that's mean that user is logged out.

I think that's all.

Comment: Why bother making a hit to logout? There really should be no need to do that. Just need to clear on the device whatever it is you need to clear such as stored data, stored username & password, etc.

Comment: If you use PHP sessions, sessions stored on the SERVER side, so probably despite you cleared everything on the device, SERVER will still remember you.

Comment: But you can't rely on the device hitting you during logout though. What if the user delete's the app? Or what if they restore their device?

Comment: Session also have timeout, so if you haven't hit 'logout', session automaticly will be destoryed in predefined time.

Comment: Precisely. So why have logout? I guess it totally depends on what you're trying to do. In general though an iOS app doesn't need to hit a logout API in my opinion. It's a pretty strange user experience as well to have to have internet access to logout and to have to wait whilst the HTTP hit is made.

Comment: Well, yeah, but there is a lot of situations, so that I can't describe totally everything here, that is not panacea, it's just my opinion.

Comment: @matt You *should* always log out explicitly if you're logging out so the server can throw away the session. It's not only good housekeeping, it also reduces the window for session hijacking etc. If your session timeout is short enough anyway and you have enough entropy in your session ids and/or are otherwise throttling hijacking attempts it really isn't a concern admittedly, but it's still good housekeeping. :)